# can i use eventEmeter in ng-container with *ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, templates, output, eventemitter

Can I use output with EventEmitter to exchange events between a template and the parent component, like in this example:

```
<div>
   <ng-container
      *ngTemplateOutlet="
        field.field.editTemplate;
        context: {
          dataItem: field
        }
      "
      (validate)="validateField(field)"
    ></ng-container>
</div>
```

For example, the template code is:

```
<ng-template let-dataItem="dataItem" #EditTemplate>
  <div
    class="noselect"
    style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%"
  >
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      [id]="'customCheckbox' + dataItem.id"
      [(ngModel)]="dataItem.isChecked"
      style="display: none"
    />
    <label
      [for]="'customCheckbox' + dataItem.id"
      (click)="onClic()"
    >
      <i
        *ngIf="dataItem.isChecked; else uncheckedIcon"
        style="cursor: pointer; color: forestgreen; font-size: 200%"
        class="material-icons icons-lg"
        >check_circle_outline</i
      >
      <ng-template #uncheckedIcon>
        <i
          placement="bottom"
          style="cursor: pointer; color: rgb(0, 110, 255); font-size: 200%"
          class="material-icons icons-lg"
          >check_circle_outline</i
        >
      </ng-template>
    </label>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

```
onClic(){
   this.validate.emit(true)
}
```

I've done this, but the event doesn't transfer in the validateField(field) methode.

Can I use output with EventEmitter to exchange events between a template and the parent component

Answer (score 0):

Yes! The Angular `EventEmitter` must be used in a child component that contains the template. So you would define the `EventEmitter` like:

`@Output() validate = new EventEmitter<boolean>();`

Try not to use `onClic` as your function name. Make it more meaningful/readable like `validateOnClick()`;

```
validateOnClick() {
   this.validate.emit(true); <---- should it always be TRUE?
}
```

In parent component:

```
validateField(field: any) {
   console.log('Validation triggered for field:', field);
}
```

Check out NgTemplateOutlet Type Checking here:

https://medium.com/@thomas.laforge/ngtemplateoutlet-type-checking-5d2dcb07a2c6